# How to Center Marker in Gmaps4rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393654/in-gmaps4rails-how-do-i-move-the-map-so-the-marker-is-in-view), I'm still having trouble with getting the marker to show at the center of the page.

My code is as follows;

In the view

```
<div class="Flexible-container">
<!--Google Maps Div-->
          <div id="map" style='width: 425; height: 425px;' frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></div>
</div>
          <!-- End of Responsive iFrame -->
          <script type="text/javascript">
          handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
          handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
            markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
            handler.map.centerOn(markers[0]);
            handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
            handler.fitMapToBounds();
            handler.map.serviceObject.setZoom(16);
          });
          </script>
```

In the controller

```
def edit
    @user = current_user
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@user) do |u, marker|
  marker.lat u.latitude
  marker.lng u.longitude
  marker.infowindow u.name
  end
end
```

CSS

```
/* Flexible iFrame */

.Flexible-container {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

.Flexible-container iframe,   
.Flexible-container object,  
.Flexible-container embed {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Currently, the marker on the page is at the corner of the container div. How do I do it so that the marker shows at the center? And is there a way to improve my map div in the view?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to know what you desire:

```
// to center on a marker
handler.map.centerOn(markers[0]); 
// to set the map zoom
handler.getMap().setZoom(16);


// to center the map AND adjust zoom to see ALL markers
handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
handler.fitMapToBounds();
```

So keep the code you prefer but dont mix it, simply

Comment: Is it necessary to setZoom after centerOn?